# I cannot parse an array of objects generated in Javascript in a Java Servlet as a JSONArray

Tags: javascript, java

I would like to create an array of objects in Javascript, then send it to a Java servlet via POST in order to read it out there.
But every time I get the error shown below in Java

My JavaScript Code looks like this:

```
var kurstermineNEW = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    var datenSatz = "";
    var kurstermin = {};
    kurstermin.Veranstaltungen_ID = $(
            '#kurstemineTbl tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(0)')
            .attr('kursterminID');
    kurstermin.Veranstaltungen_KursartID = $("#kursSuche").val();
    kurstermin.Veranstaltungen_Startdatum = formatDateSQL($(
            '#kurstemineTbl tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(0)').text());
   [...]
  kurstermineNEW.push(kurstermin);

  }
```

Here , the Result in my Java Class:

[image]

And at last,the error code:

> org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: The string you showed _isn't JSON_. It looks more like some sort of customized SQL language. In general, you should use `JSON.stringify` in JavaScript if you're doing this sort of thing by hand (which you shouldn't).

Comment: As chrylis said, it is not JSON. We need more information to help you: could you show us the code to POST your array? What is the expected result?